# Will a filtering on a field benefit from a composite key that contains that field, among others?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

If I have a composite key (primary or plain index) based on fields, say Year(int) and Ord(int), will filtering `WHERE Year=2011` benefit from that key or will it ignore it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you filter on the n left-most columns (where n >= 1), then that index could at least be used (might still be ignored due to other facts).

So if your index is on `(Year, Ord)` and you filter by `Year` - then yes, that index might be used.

However, if you filter on `Ord` alone, that filter will not even be considered - it cannot be used.

Comment: So in practice I should create two additional indexes, one for each column, if I plan to filter sometimes on one and sometimes on the other?

Comment: @Boris B.: Indexes have overhead, so add them only if performance requires it.  It's perfectly OK for a rarely used filter to take a bit longer.

Comment: @Andomar: I know indexes have overhead when inserting or updating (sometimes even when selecting, if they are out-of-date). I want to absolutely maximize filtered-select performance, but I don't want to create redundant indexes, hence the original question.

Comment: @BorisB.: if you need to filter just on `Year` and just on `Ord` other times, then yes - you need two separate indices. A compound index with both columns will **only** help you for filter on `Year` alone, or on `Year` and `Ord` in the same SELECT query

Comment: It might still do a scan of the narrower index in preference to a clustered index scan though even if  `Ord` is not the leading column especially if it expects few lookups to be needed.